# How to have 2 background colors on a single image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

```
 <div class="row bg-white">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-blue">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="screenshot_water"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">some text </div>
    </div>
```

I have 2 sections on the top of my website:

1. white background
2. blue background

What I want is for image to have 10% of it with a white background, and the rest blue.

Given that I have a row to deal with, how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using gradient? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the CSS opacity property to the image.

```
.opaque {
  /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
  /* ...but not required as filter works too */
  /* should come BEFORE filter */
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // IE8

  /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
  /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); // IE 5-7

  /* Modern Browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

You can read more about opacity at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 0):

Add overall in one main div

```
<div class="row bg-white-blue">
  <div class="col-lg-6"> </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"> </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="screenshot_water"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">some text </div>
</div>
```

And then add CSS to that main div class. For example

```
.bg-white-blue {
  background: linear-gradient(black 10%, blue 50%);
}
```

Comment: I don't want a gradient.  the colors should be solid not gradient.